# How would I do a NOT IN in Razor <td>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, razor, styles

I want to highlight the value returned, if it is not a "*P*" or an "*S*". I'm not sure how to do this with inline Razor style. There is a style section for `myFalse` and `myTrue` styles.

**This works for changing display values,** 
however, it's Boolean. I need `OR, ||, NOT IN`. Something like that.

```
<td align='center'>
<span class='@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>
@(m.IsTOTPresent ? "POSITIVE" : "")
</span>
</td>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
<td align="center">
<span class='@(m.SampType Not In("R","S") ? "myTrue" :   "myFalse")'>
@m.SampType
</span>
</td>
```

The styles work for regular use in [html](/questions/tagged/html). I can change them all sorts of ways, so the issue isn't the styles (they are simple: red color or light-grey background).

Does anyone know what's wrong, or have any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Contains` extension method:

```
<td align="center">
    <span class='@(!new[] { "P", "S" }.Contains(m.SampType) ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>
        @m.SampType
    </span>
</td>
```

or if you prefer:

```
<td align="center">
    <span class='@(m.SampType != "P" && m.SampType != "S" ? "myTrue" : "myFalse")'>
        @m.SampType
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Yup Yup Yup. That worked. Straight off the clipboard. Copy and paste. Thank your for your quick response.

Comment: No, I tried the second one. Maybe it didn't work because I used "||" instead of "&&". sheez